Can you explain why std::ranges::find won't work?
I am puzzled as to why it is apparently impossible to compare a subrange of std::string_view with a std::string_view. I mean they ought to be of the same base type and thus comparable to each other?
Can someone explain why this won't work?
https://godbolt.org/z/3Y6zMaTEv
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string_view> forbidden{"123", "4fe", "bad"};
    std::string_view subject = "foo545jdsf4fesub\n55324123434\nsomebadstuff";

    for (auto&& line : subject | std::ranges::views::split('\n')) {
        std::ranges::any_of(forbidden, [&line](auto&& bad) {
            return std::ranges::find(line, bad) != line.end(); // Complains about something being not callable?!
        });
    }
    return 0;
}


You mean ranges::search?

@康桓瑋 or possibly string_view::find?

@康桓瑋 std::ranges::search works for some reason or another, thank you. I would love to understand though why find does not compile though.


why it is apparently impossible to compare a subrange of std::string_view with a std::string_view.

You aren't trying to do that. You are trying to compare a char with a std::string_view. std::ranges::find compares individual elements of the "haystack" view for equality with the "needle".
You might have been confused by the member std::string_view::find, which does search for a substring.
If you only want to know if the bad text is in the line:
for (auto&& line : subject | std::views::split('\n')) {
    std::ranges::any_of(forbidden, [&line](auto bad) {
        return std::ranges::contains_subrange(line, bad);
    });
}

If you want to do know where in the line the bad word is found:
for (auto&& line : subject | std::views::split('\n')) {
    std::ranges::any_of(forbidden, [&line](auto bad) {
        auto res = std::ranges::search(line, bad);
        // use position of match
        return res.size();
    });
}


If you want to find out whether the split substring contains a forbidden substring, you can just use string_view::contains:
std::vector<std::string_view> forbidden{"123", "4fe", "bad"};
std::string_view subject = "foo545jdsf4fesub\n55324123434\nsomebadstuff";

for (auto line : subject | std::ranges::views::split('\n')) {
  if (std::ranges::any_of(forbidden, [line](auto bad) {
    return std::string_view(line).contains(bad);
  })) {
    // match
  }
}


std::ranges::contains_subrange(line, bad) also works

@Caleth, I think string_view::contains is a bit more efficient as it specializes in strings.
